# Receiving 403 error and site not refreshing elements from tab-panel when looping through dropdown options in selenium with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, selenium-chromedriver, http-status-code-403

In using selenium library in python, my web scraping program so far is able to grab the data I need from simpletire.com and works almost 90%. The issue I'm having is that when I loop through the dropdown menu, click each tire size, and the page loads...the tech specs tab panel is not refreshing to reflect that tire size (i.e. the container of data I want). Therefore, my program only scrapes the tire data for tire size 1...and keeps extracting the data for tire size 1 even though I am looping through each tire size option in the dropdown menu. I obviously want the data unique to each tire size.

Example link: https://simpletire.com/brands/american-tourer-tires/touring-a-s#curationPos=none&curationSeq=none&curationSource=none&delivery=Del3&itemId=208796&mpn=AMSYTH0268&pageSource=PDP&productPos=none&rad=BE&region=r2&tireSize=215-70r15&userRegion=2&userZip=19125&v=1&zip=19125

I noticed that if I scroll down in the middle of the page, I eventually see a 403 error which means my request must be getting blocked. Even when I click on the next option manually, the same static data for tire size 1 is still showing and never loads the new elements.

When I manually go to my chrome browser, without python, and I cycle through the tire sizes in the dropdown I can see the data reflecting in real time. How do I resolve this 403 issue and loading the new elements when I click each new tire size?

Below is my code:

```
def extract_data(url, service, output_folder, filename):
    # variable to keep track of start time of executing this function
    start = time.time()
    # use selenium to open URL with chrome driver
    driver = get_driver(url, service)

    # wait for pop-up to appear that's contained in an <iframe> tag
    iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "attentive_creative"))
    )

    # find and click "X" button to close pop-up
    try:
        close_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "closeIconContainer"))
        )
        close_button.click()
        driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
    except:
        print("Pop up message was not able to be dismissed.")

    # find the dropdown menu, click it, and retrieve the tire size options
    dropdown = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, "//*[@id='selectSizeButton']/div[1]/h2/div/span/button"
    )
    dropdown.click()
    option_container = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, "//*[@id='selectSizeButton']/div[1]/h2/div/span[2]"
    )
    tire_sizes = [
        tire_size.text.strip()
        for tire_size in option_container.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-9gtu0e")
    ]

    # close the dropdown menu by hitting the escape key on keyboard
    try:
        hit_esc = webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
    except:
        print("Tire size dropdown was not able to be clicked or closed.")

    # get dictionary of tire data
    tire_data_dict = get_dict(driver, tire_sizes, dropdown, option_container)

    # convert dictionary to a Pandas dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(tire_data_dict, orient="index")
    # clean df
    df = clean_df(df)
    print(df.head())
    
    # export dataframe to excel and open on desktop
    output_path = Path(output_folder, f"{filename}.xlsx")
    df.to_excel(output_path, index=False)
    os.startfile(output_path)

    # stats to calculcate how long this function ran for
    end = time.time()
    result_time = end - start
    time_formatted = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(result_time))
    # display message to show status and total time execution of program
    sg.popup_no_titlebar(
        f"Done! Tire sizes exported in file called '{filename}.xlsx'.\n\nExecution Time (hh:mm:ss): {time_formatted}"
    )


def get_driver(url, service):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    service = Service(rf"{service}")
    chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
    chrome_browser.get(rf"{url}")
    chrome_browser.maximize_window()
    return chrome_browser


def get_dict(driver, tire_sizes, dropdown, option_container):
    # loop through the options and extract data
    i = 0
    tire_data = {}
    while i < len(tire_sizes):
        # open the dropdown and select tire size
        dropdown.click()
        option_labels = option_container.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "label")
        option_labels[i].click()
        # wait for URL to change with 5 seconds timeout
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
        # get the page source for that tire size, parse the HTML, and scrape data
        tech_specs_data = scrape_tech_specs_data(driver)
        # assign the tire_size as the key and tech_specs_data as the value (a nested dictionary)
        tire_data[tire_sizes[i]] = tech_specs_data
        # update tracker variable
        i += 1
    # exit chromedriver
    driver.quit()
    return tire_data


def scrape_tech_specs_data(driver):
    tech_specs_data = {}
    # find the container holding the tech specs data and loop through zip object to fill tech_specs_data
    container = driver.find_element(By.ID, "SiteProductSpecs")
    columns = container.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-1ojsquv")
    values = container.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "css-4yq70y")
    for column, value in zip(columns, values):
        tech_specs_data[column.text.strip()] = value.text.strip()
    return tech_specs_data


def clean_df(df):
    # reset index and relabel index column to "Tire Size"
    df = df.reset_index()
    df = df.rename(columns={"index": "Tire Size"})
    return df
```